# How to get audio files on my phone using Ionic 2 Cordova plugins?

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have tried the Ionic mediaPlugin

```
import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';

var file = new MediaPlugin('path/to/file.mp3');
```

I'm still confused on how to do that. All I want to do is to create something like a media player, that gets all the audio on a users android phone, and to play and pause it too.

Comment: could u check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714368/could-not-make-audio-playback   u may get something

Answer (score 2):

Check this [tutorial](http://www.erikschierboom.com/2016/09/02/ionic2-audio-recorder/) first it will guide you. However check [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) too, it will tell you where you have to store your data.

If you do it on android, you should use *externalDataDirectory*.

```
  this.filePath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;

  this.mediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin(this.filePath + this.directoryName + "/" + this.actualAudioFileName);
```

After this you can find your data under the following folder on your phone
*Android/data/yourApplicationId/files/yourDirectoryName*

Comment: this really helped me