# ionic2 create .wav file and get the path for the cordova media-plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic2

i'm trying to create a .wav file and get it with the cordova media-plugin and it keeps saying that the resource is unknown. this is the code:

```
private startRecording() {
    let filename = "myRecord.wav";
    File.createFile(cordova.file.documentsDirectory, filename, true).then((result)=>{
      console.log(result);
      this._fileRecord = new MediaPlugin(cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'myRecord.wav');
      this._fileRecord.startRecord();
    },
    (error)=>{
      console.log("error");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396525/how-to-get-audio-files-on-my-phone-using-ionic-2-cordova-plugins/42736196#42736196).

You should use `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` on Android, and `cordova.file.dataDirectory` on iOS.

Comment: thanks, it works. I just had to replace in the cordova.file.dataDirectory the "file:///" with "cdvfile://" (let path = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    path = path.replace("file:///", "cdvfile://"));